# Using flex to achieve two rows and one column layout

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to use flexbox to achieve a column layout with an element "floated" to the right.

**Something like this**:

[image]

Thing is, I cannot alter the HTML since it's an embedded form so trying to achieve this via pure CSS.

So far, I have this:

```css
.form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-form {
  width: 100%;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

fieldset {
  border: 0;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
}

.form-columns-2 {
  display: flex;
}

.form-columns-2 input:first-child {
  margin-bottom: .5em
}

.form-columns-1 textarea {
  height: 100%
}
.submit-wrapper{
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="form-container">
    <div class="form-form">
      <form>
        <fieldset class="form-columns-2">
          <input type="text" placeholder="test">
          <input type="text" placeholder="test">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-columns-2">
          <input type="text" placeholder="test">
          <input type="text" placeholder="test">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset class="form-columns-1">
          <textarea placeholder="test">Text</textarea>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="submit-wrapper">
          <div class="actions">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Edit:**

I also need the submit button to **sit under** the textarea, but since the `.submit-wrapper` is a direct child of `form`, the only way I can see addressing this is by adding `flex-direction: column;` to `form`. However, this turns the whole layout into a column, which I do not want.

Comment: does it have to be flexbox? Have you tried using display: grid here?

Comment: Also note that flexbox and fieldset *do not play nice*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are apllying `display: flex` to the wrong elements and to more elements than you need to.

Check this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwPoEP

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
fieldset{
  border:0;
}
textarea{
  resize:none;
}

form { // you want the form to be a flex box, not everything!
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.form-columns-2 {
  display: flex; //you can use other options here, this works but you can use display: block on the inputs for example
}

// this 2 are just to make it look like the image
.form-columns-2 input:first-child {
  margin-bottom: .5em
}
.form-columns-1 textarea {
  height: 100%
}
```

Comment: ah, cheers! Followup question, I'm trying to get the submit button to sit under the textarea. I've updated my original post to show the latest code and query. If you could look at that, that'll be cool?

Comment: Hmmm, with that new requirement I would use a grid layout, something like `display: grid; grid-template-areas: 'inputs1 inputs2 textarea' 'inputs1 inputs2 submit';` and then you can position the items with `.submit-wrapper {gird-area: submit}` `.form-columns-1 {grid-area: textarea}`.